# Structuring Data In Firebase

Tags: firebase

I'm contemplating using Firebase for an upcoming project, but before doing so I want to make sure I can develop a data structure that will meet my purposes.   I'm interested in tracking horse race results for approximately 25 racetracks across the US. My initial impression was that my use case aligned nicely with the [Firebase Weather Data Set](https://publicdata-weather.firebaseio.com).  The Weather data set is organized by city and then in various time series: currently, hourly, daily and minutely.

My initial thought was that I could follow a similar approach and use the 25 tracks as cities and then organize by years, months, days and races.

This structure lends itself nicely to accessing data from a particular track, but suppose that also want to access data across all tracks. For example, access data for all tracks for races that occurred in 2014 and had more than 10 horses.

Questions:

1. Does my proposed data structure limit me to queries by track only or would I still be able to query across tracks, years, days, months, etc. and incorporate any and all of the various meta data attributes: number of horses, distance of race, etc.
2. Given, my interest in freeform querying is there another data structure that would be more advantageous?
3. Is Firebase similar to Mongodb and have issues with collections (lists) that grow or can one continue to push to a list without pre allocating  or worrying about sharding?

I believe my confusion stems from url/path nature of the data storage.

EDIT:

[image]

Here is a sample of what I had in mind:

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Since you seem to have a specific data structure in mind, show us an example of the data in that structure. That will make it a lot easier to discuss pros and cons (although that may still leave the question rather broad for StackOverflow, but we'll see).

Answer (score 3):

I would think that you would want to organize by horse first.  I guess it depends what you are deriving from the data. 
One horse could be at different tracks.

Horses table

```
* Horsename
-----Date
-----Track
-----Racenumber
-----Gate
-----Jockey
-----Place
-----Odds
-----Mud?
```

Races table

```
----Track
----Racenumber
----Date
----Time
----NumberOfHorses
```

Link the tables and you could get at any one part of it.

Comment: When you say "link" the tables, what do you mean? I was under the impression that Firebase, like mongodb, did not support joins.

Comment: @Frank_van_Puffelen I've provided a sample of what I had in mind.

Comment: You are correct, it is denormalized.  But that is an exercise not yet ready to be dealt with.  I use the term loosely.  You can link it with dual query code or in strict firebase style and use the uid style with the repeated data.  You get a lot more writes, but still make few quicker reads.